# android.support.design.widget.TabItem cannot be cast to android.view.ViewGroup

Tags: java, android, dialog, fragment

im getting following error on run time.

> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                     Process: com.example.usamaakmal.trackpoint, PID: 8774
>                     android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: android.support.design.widget.TabItem cannot be cast to android.view.ViewGroup
>                     Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.support.design.widget.TabItem cannot be cast to
>   android.view.ViewGroup
>                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:870)
>                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:832)
>                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:872)
>                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:832)
>                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:872)
>                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:832)
>                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:518)
>                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:426)
>                         at com.example.usamaakmal.trackpoint.PresentationLayer.Dialogs.DateTimePickerDialog.onCreateView(DateTimePickerDialog.java:20)
>                         at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2354)
>                         at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1419)
>                         at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1740)
>                         at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1809)
>                         at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:799)
>                         at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManager.java:2580)
>                         at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2367)
>                         at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:2322)
>                         at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:2229)
>                         at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:700)
>                         at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:761)
>                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
>                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:156)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6523)
>                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:942)
>                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:832)

My XML layout is following

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="Select Date And Time"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:id="@+id/tv_date_time_title"/>


    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/date_time_tab_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/tv_date_time_title"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true">

        <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
            android:id="@+id/tab_date_item"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Date">

            <DatePicker android:id="@+id/dp_date_picker"></DatePicker>

        </android.support.design.widget.TabItem>

        <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
            android:id="@+id/tab_time_item"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Time">

            <TimePicker android:id="@+id/tp_time_picker"></TimePicker>
        </android.support.design.widget.TabItem>
    </android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

and my custom Dialog fragment class is below

```
public class DateTimePickerDialog extends DialogFragment {
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.date_time_picker_layout,container,false);
        return view;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `TabItem` extends `View`. [Reference here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TabItem.html). Therefore you can't include another view inside the `TabItem`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="Select Date And Time"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:id="@+id/tv_date_time_title"/>


    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/date_time_tab_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/tv_date_time_title"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true">

        <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
            android:id="@+id/tab_date_item"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Date" />

        <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
            android:id="@+id/tab_time_item"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Time" />
    </android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Okay so then how can i show date and time picker in the tab items? @Kobayashi

Comment: Please ask another question. That for stackoverflow roles.